# On tapping a button in native-script app the function is not working

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

In Native-script app, on tapping a button the function is not working(not called). When I make any change or even write console.log('hi') inside that function then it start works. But when I go to another screen and come back to the previous screen and tap the button again, it stops working again. I don't understand what's the issue is ?

This is the html code :

```
<Button class="alarms-btn" text="Alarms" (tap)="onClickActiveAlarm()"></Button>
```

This is .ts code :

```
public onClickActiveAlarm() {
    if (_.size(this.alarms) === 0) {
      this.snackWarn('No Alarms')
      return
    }

    this.routerExtensions.navigate(['/', alarms])
  }
```

Comment: it sounds like your app is silently erroring, are there any logs in the console?

Comment: Nothing in console. I got no error.

Comment: Which platform you are finding this issue? Can you create a Playground Sample where this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj Issue is on Android but working fine on iOS.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should use @tap instead of (tap) ?

Comment: `(tap)` is the correct identifier as the `()` denotes a method

Comment: You use `@tap` is Vue syntax for event binding, not Angular.